# Feynman diagram

Tags: standard-model, feynman-diagrams, bosons, mesons, gluons

[image: Bt decay]

In this picture first diagram, can't the gluon be a $Z$ boson?
Similarly, can't the $Z$ boson in the second diagram be a gluon?

Comment: have you considered the flavors at the vertices? gluons do not change flavors? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/qrkdec.html , the gluon does not have weak interactions,

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compare the effects and roles played by the gluon and the *Z* in the diagrams, they are both flavor diagonal; the *Z* cannot change color, but the gluon can, but does not have to―recall $\lambda_3$ and  $\lambda_8$ are color diagonal.

So, in the first diagram, you are allowed to supplant the gluon with a *Z*, which, however, suppresses the amplitude enormously, given the huge mass $m_Z=91 $GeV in its propagator (entering quadratically).

You can also do the reverse in the second diagram, which would give you an enhancement  amounting to undoing   the  above suppression, unless there is a subtle color projection suppression, which might not be obvious to me at all...  So I should be puzzled by the presence of the *Z* in the second diagram. Where do these diagrams come from? Looks like an exam.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, click on the checkmark.